# Is it possible to reverse order a tableView? I search a lot for a solution but nothing works

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

I want to leave scroll direction but show my cells in reversed version, I already use reversed()[indexPath.row] for my cell, and know I need just revers what I have.

```
----------
label 1
----------
label 2
----------
label 3
----------
empty
----------
empty
----------

scroll direction
   |
   |
   v
```

Desired result:

```
----------
empty
----------
empty
----------
label 3
----------
label 2
----------
label 1
----------
scroll direction
   |
   |
   v
```

Comment: Reverse your data model.

Comment: I agree but I suppose rbaldwin mean _data source_

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, thanks :).  OP:  What purpose do the empty cells serve at the top of the `UITableView`?

Answer (score 0):

By default in a table-view as of iOS 13.5 there are "empty" cells drawn which will not show up if you reverse your model. In order to achieve that, you need to provide some data to the cells and then render them empty.

Answer (score 0):

you can reverse your data model , for example `var characters: [Character] = ["C", "a", "f", "é"]
characters.reverse()
print(characters)
// Prints "["é", "f", "a", "C"]`